# Report to find objects of a segw project and put them on a request

Tags: request, abap

I'm new in SAP and during my practicing I came up with a 'problem': when I was transporting my project to another system I had to manually include some objects that were in other requests. 
So now I'm trying to make a report to join all the objects related to a segw project in a single request. My idea is passing the Project ID or name to my report find the objects, create a request and put all of them into it.

I've already found something. When creating a segw project and generate it, the request has:
- Class (ABAP objects) with the DPC and MPC
- SAP Gateway Business Suite Enablement - Model
- SAP Gateway BSE - Service Builder Project
- SAP Gateway Business Suite Enablement - Service

I've found two tables that help me to get DPC and MPC objects:
TMDIR, VSEOCLASS.

Am I in the right path? Is there a way to find all related objects to the project or I'll need to find them separately like the DPC and MPC I've already found?

Thanks!

Comment: From my experience, when you create and activate, *all* affected objects are added to your transport request. What **exactly** is missing from your point of view?

Comment: Put the SEGW project under a package, generate the SEGW project and include all the objects under the package into the transport request.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your SEGW objects reside in a single package which is usually the case when you create SEGW project from scratch:

```
DATA: l_trkorr TYPE trkorr,
      l_package TYPE devclass VALUE 'ZSEGW_P'.

cl_pak_package_queries=>get_all_subpackages( EXPORTING im_package     = l_package
                                             IMPORTING et_subpackages = DATA(lt_descendant) ).

INSERT VALUE cl_pak_package_queries=>ty_subpackage_info( package = l_package ) INTO TABLE lt_descendant.

SELECT pgmid, object, obj_name FROM tadir
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_segw_objects)
   FOR ALL ENTRIES IN @lt_descendant
 WHERE devclass = @lt_descendant-package.

DATA(instance) = cl_adt_cts_management=>create_instance( ).

LOOP AT lt_segw_objects ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_obj>).
  TRY.
      instance->insert_objects_in_wb_request( EXPORTING pgmid        = <fs_obj>-pgmid
                                                        object       = <fs_obj>-object
                                                        obj_name     = CONV trobj_name( <fs_obj>-obj_name )
                                              IMPORTING result       = DATA(result)
                                                        request      = DATA(request)
                                              CHANGING  trkorr       = l_trkorr ).
    CATCH cx_adt_cts_insert_error.
  ENDTRY.
ENDLOOP.
```

This snippet creates transport request with number `l_trkorr` and as soon as this var is not changed put all remainign objects in the same request.

**WARNING**: this will **not** work if the objects are locked (in another request) and will give you `cx_adt_cts_insert_error` exception. There is no way to unlock objects programmatically, only via SE03 tool.